# Can Checksum alerts make it to the end user?

Tags: sql-server

I've been reading

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/lets-corrupt-sql-server-database-together/#comment-2539669

and I've got some databases with Torn Page Detection that I need to change to Checksum. I've already run (and scheduled) my CheckDB's and we've got no corruption.

**Question:** If I enable checksum, and a page gets corrupted, can any of my end users get errors in their applications?

Comment: 1 - Changing the torn page detection to checksum is not sufficient on it's own.  You need to rebuild ALL of your existing indexes and tables to generate the checksums.  Otherwise, the checksums will only be on pages that were touched after the change.     2 - No, that particular error is severity 0 so the client won't see anything.  You should have an alert set up for message 825.  Good example of that and other alerts are here (I'm not affiliated)  https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/the-accidental-dba-day-17-of-30-configuring-alerts-for-high-severity-problems/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any corruption alerts can make it to the end user.

To see it yourself, grab one of the corrupt databases from [Steve Stedman's Corruption Challenge](http://stevestedman.com/server-health/database-corruption-challenge/). Attach the corrupt database to one of your development environments, and run the query that Steve describes for that database. You'll see corruption errors - just as your end users would.

Your application (C#, Java, whatever) can be coded to trap incoming errors and display different things to the users, but that's an exercise left for the reader.